# NVDA screen Reader ignores aria-current ="date" in top-bottom Navigation

Tags: wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda, wcag2.0

I am working on an application for disabled people in which NVDA screen reader is supposed to read out the current date if the user hit on element(date picker/calendar/cleave) with tab. When Navigating from top to bottom of page NVDA is ignoring aria=current="date" ( doesn't reads out as current date), but reads out the same date when navigating from b0ttom-top of the page.

reference of code snippet:

```
    <tag
attribute1
attribute2
aria-current="date"
>
<input /calendar (could be calendar in place of input)
attribute1
type="date"
aria-current="date"
attribute2
more attributes
>
</tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`aria-current`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-current) is supposed to tell you which element within a set of elements is the current one.  It has various values with the most common one being *"true"*.

I just tried the various values with NVDA on both Firefox and Chrome and they all seemed to work.

```html
<button>foo</button>
<button aria-current="true">foo</button>
<button aria-current="page">foo</button>
<button aria-current="step">foo</button>
<button aria-current="location">foo</button>
<button aria-current="date">foo</button>
<button aria-current="time">foo</button>
```

The results from NVDA were:

- *"foo  button"*
- *"foo  button,    current"*
- *"foo  button,    current page"*
- *"foo  button,    current step"*
- *"foo  button,    current location"*
- *"foo  button,    current date"*
- *"foo  button,    current time"*

Comment: any suggestion on how to do this for dynamic rendering? , did this work for you from both top and bottom navigation? For me when I navigate from top,it doesn't recognize the aria-current,when I tab from bottom of the page it reads out as current date(ex, 14,current date)

Comment: It did not matter if I tabbed forward or backward.  It always announced as listed in the answer.  If you have an example page, I can test it.